# In Facebook's Graph API, how do I get all the friends of my friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want a list of friends of my friends. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's no way to do this anymore. I tried this FQL query:

```
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 IN 
    (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = <UID>)
```

And I get an error message that says this:

> Can't lookup all friends of . Can only lookup for the logged in user (), or friends of the logged in user with the appropriate permission

Additionally, there's no `friends_friends` [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) or anything similar. Conversely, you can get your friends' likes using the `friends_likes` permission, so this looks like an intentional omission.

In essence, it looks like you have to have an install from a given user to get that user's friends.